# How do I programmatically open a UDP port in the Windows Firewall?

Tags: c++, networking, udp, port

Is it possible to programmatically open UDP ports in the Windows Firewall in C/C++? I googled but did not find a solution. Only solutions found go through the Firewall's graphical interface. I need to automatically open a port after installing a program to accept connections from clients.

Comment: A websearch for *windows firewall api win32* should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: I would _hope_ that you would need to be running 'As Administrator' to do this (so maybe do it in your installer).